# Where to put the header function

Tags: php

Okay this is definitley an easy question and a stupid one but since I have been developing on localhost i didn't even realise it was a problem. The header to redirect to members page in the loginscript is not working because it is positioned incorrectly. This did not cause a problem on wamp but is on the live server. The script is included in an html file for reasons too long to tell here. Nothing is echoed in the script until something goes wrong but then the script is stopped. Where should i put the redirect header?

Here is the login script:

```
<?php 

// Connects to your Database 

include ("database.php");


 //Checks if there is a login cookie

 if(isset($_SESSION['username']))


 //if there is, it logs you in and directes you to the members page

 {  
    echo '<div id="probwarn"><t1><b>You are already logged in! You do not need to do it again.</b></t1></div>';

}


 //if the login form is submitted 

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // if form has been submitted

$flag = 0; // Safety net, if this gets to 1 at any point in the process, we don't upload.

 // makes sure they filled it in

if(!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['pass']) {

    echo('<div id="probwarn"><t1>You did not fill in a required field.</t1></div>');
$flag = $flag + 1;
    }

// checks it against the database





    $pass = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));
    $username = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']));




   $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '".$username."'")or die(mysql_error());



 //Gives error if user dosen't exist

 $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);

 if ($check2 == 0) {
if($flag == 0) {
    echo('<div id="probwarn"><t1>You must <a href="register.html">    <b>register</b></a> first.</t1></div>') ;


            }
    $flag = $flag + 1;
    }           

 $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '".$username."'")or     die(mysql_error());
 $pass = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));
    $username = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']));

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))     

 {

 $_POST['pass'] = stripslashes($_POST['pass']);

$info['password'] = stripslashes($info['password']);

$_POST['pass'] = md5($_POST['pass']);



 //gives error if the password is wrong

if ($_POST['pass'] != $info['password']) {
 if($flag == 0) {
    echo('<div id="probwarn"><t1>Incorrect password, please try again.</t1>    </div>');
$flag ++;
     } }

   }        





 // if login is ok then we add a cookie 
 if($flag == 0) {
 $pass = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));
 $username = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']));



 $_SESSION['username']=$username;
 $_SESSION['password']=$pass;

 //then redirect them to the members area
//THIS IS THE HEADER 
 header("Location: ../members.html");





 } 

 } 

 else 





 // if they are not logged in 

 ?> 
 LOGIN FORM IS USUALLY HERE
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @Truth thanks very much i will get learning

Comment: @Truth: While a helpful comment, it would be even more helpful if it highlighted the ease of use over the positive security by-effects. It's not necessary to lie about a hypothetical "deprecation", when the manual just says ["discouraged"](http://php.net/mysql_query) for now. Redundant url shortening is redundant.

Comment: Perhaps your script is echoing something before the redirect? Remember that headers can only be set before any output (ie html) is sent to the client.

Comment: @mario: I can only fit 600 characters in a comment, I can't outline everything in that comment, that's why the tutorials are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to `exit` after setting a Location header. Unless you know exactly what you're doing, you should ALWAYS put `exit` (or `die()`) after a Location header.

Comment: `die(header("Location: ..."));` and probably some error interception because output out renders headers meaningless.

Comment: Well, that's one way of doing it. Not how I'd do it, personally, since it's a bit confusing. I'd just put the `die()` immediately after the `header()` call.

Comment: Yep, I accidentally hit enter. :P

Comment: Thanks for the info and i have done it but still hasn't solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

you can use header('Location: address') everywhere of your code, but it's better to use exit() function after header, if redirection not executed, other codes doesn't execute.

Comment: I used exit function. Tried die as well but that jsut kills the rest of the script after login. No redirection takes place

Comment: if this is not working use javascript redirection:
<script>location='../members.html'</script>